# Как по индексу получить значение перечисления?

Tags: java

Вот есть такой класс с энумом:

```
public class Segment {

private SegmentValue value;

//-----===== getter и setter всех полей ====-----

public SegmentValue getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(SegmentValue value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static enum Age implements SegmentValue{
    AGE1("-18"),
    AGE2("19-24"),
    AGE3("25-34"),
    AGE4("35-44"),
    AGE5("45+");

    private String value;

    Age(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы по индексу получать значение энума? Поясню: нужно сгенерировать случайный объект из энума Age. Сгенерировать случайное число от 0 до 4 - не проблема. Проблема в том, как по нему вернуть значение энума.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы умеете сгенерировать случайное число от 0 до 4, то в чем проблема?

```
Age[] ages = Age.values();
Age randomAge = ages[randInt]; //randInt - случайное число
```

Answer (score 2):

Решенее простое, первое: ввести еще два поля в энум:

```
public static enum Age implements SegmentValue{
    AGE1("-18", 0, 18),
    AGE2("19-24", 19, 24),
    AGE3("25-34", 25, 34),
    AGE4("35-44", 35, 44),
    AGE5("45+", 45, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    private String value;
    private int minAge;
    private int maxAge;

    Age(String value, int minAge, int maxAge) {
        this.value = value;
        this.minAge = minAge;
        this.maxAge = maxAge;
    }
```

Решение сложнее - парсить value.

Ну а потом что в первом случаи что во втором циклом перебрать:

```
public Age getAge(int param/String param){//тут все зависит от входногопараметра
    for(Age age : Age.values()){
      if(условиена вхождение в интервал){
        return age;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Понравилось первое решение, только не до конца его понял - во-первых, зачем вводить дополнительно 2 занчения в энумы?

А нельзя без присваивания значений делать? И без перебора циклом?

Comment: потому что у вас условие будет, если в первом случаи, то
if(param >= age.minValue && param <= age.maxValue){
   return age;
}
Может можно и лучше как-то написать, но лучше плохой, но работающий вариант, чем хороший, не работающий :)

Answer (score 2):

Не хотите вводить дополнительные параметры можете парсить строку сами:

```
public class TestEnum
{
    enum AgeRange
    {
        AGE1 ( "-18" ), AGE2 ( "19-24" ), AGE3 ( "25-34" ), AGE4 ( "35-44" ), AGE5 ( "45+" ) ;

        private String value ;
        private int lower, upper ;

        private AgeRange ( String value )
        {
            this.value = value ;
            this.lower = parseLower ( value ) ;
            this.upper = parseUpper ( value ) ;
        }

        private int parseUpper ( String value )
        {
            // TODO implement
            return 0 ;
        }

        private int parseLower ( String value )
        {
            // TODO implement
            return 0 ;
        }

        private boolean isInRange ( int age )
        {
            return this.lower <= age && age <= this.upper ;
        }

        public String toString ()
        {
            return value ;
        }

        public static AgeRange valueOf ( int age )
        {
            for ( AgeRange item : values () )
            {
                if ( item.isInRange ( age ) )
                {
                    // item found
                    return item ;
                }
            }
            return null ;
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 99 ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println ( i + " / " + AgeRange.valueOf ( i ) ) ;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно ввести в энум интовые ID, уникальные для каждого элемента (инкремент от 0). И наконец-то почитать хоть какую-то книжку по Java...

Comment: а как ввести итоговые айдишники непосредственно в энум?

Comment: Не итоговые, а интовые. Примерно так:

    public static enum Age implements SegmentValue
    {
        private static int maxid = 0;
        private int id;

        Age(String value) 
        {
            this.id = this.maxid++;
            this.value = value;
        }

Comment: А как потом обратиться к энуму, скажем, под индексом 2?
У всех же айдишник один и тот же получатся - 0
Изменил private на public и вывел вот это:    out.println(Segment.Age.AGE4.id); - получились только лишь нули