# Присвоить значение enum объекту коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, enum

У меня есть коллекция мапа, где ключ это `Integer`, а значение это класс книг, в которых две стринги. Я пишу библиотеку книг. В `enum` у меня есть жанры книг. Как мне присвоить жанр из `enum` каждой книге, которая находится в моей коллекции и вывести через `switch`, в параметры которого я пишу жанр и он выводит все книги с данным жанром.

Код:

```java
public enum Genre {
    ACTION,
    COMEDY,
    DRAMA,
    FANTASY;

    public static Genre getGenre(String genre) {
        switch (genre.toUpperCase()) {
            case "COMDEY": return …
        }
    }
}
```

Так же у меня есть коллекция, где лежит класс книг. Я хочу из `enum` каждой книге присвоить свой жанр, лежащий в том самом enum и с помощью метода `switch` выводить все книги с жанром, в который пользователь вводит жанр книги. Вопрос, как мне присвоить значение `enum` объекту класса?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправил, теперь все должно быть в порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как мне присвоить значение enum объекту коасса?

Это странный вопрос. Вы можете в классе объявить поле типа вашего enum'а (читайте вдумчиво) и просто присвоить ему значение вашего enum'а. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/160807/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) вам ссылка, как вытянуть значение из enum'а для удобства

Comment: Хмм. Все равно не понял. У меня есть коллекция из фильмов, их 100. Мне надо к ним через switch передать значения из enum. Как мне этим фильмам передать значения enum. Может кто то другой может доходчивее объяснить, буду признателен. П.с. Я самоучка, немного с трудом дается)

Comment: @KirilKarpuhin у вас коллекция чего? Коллекция объектов типа "Фильм". Вы в класс "Фильм" просто добавьте поле типа вашего enum, тогда у каждого объект коллекции будет доступной это поле, для того, что бы задать ему соответствующее значение

Comment: Спасибо Вам, я ближе к решению задачи. Только теперь вопрос, который меня больше всего мучал. У меня несколько фильмов одинакогого жанра. Как мне через switch вывести все фильмы с одинаковым жанром? То есть нужен метод, на вход который принимает строку (жанр) и он должен через switch вывести все фильмы данного жанра. Это по сути и был основной вопрос. Спасибо еще раз!